# Килограмм мандарин или килограмм мандаринов?

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение, существительные

*Килограмм **мандарин*** *или килограмм **мандаринов***? То же и с помидорами.
Как правильно? Слышу и так и эдак.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Названия плодов, фруктов и овощей, представляющие собой существительные мужского рода, в начальной форме оканчивающиеся на твердый согласный (апельсин, баклажан, помидор, мандарин), в форме родительного падежа множественного числа имеют окончание -*ов*: пять апельсинов, килограмм баклажанов, Новый год без **мандаринов**, салат из **помидоров**.